# Firebase order query $UIDs by value at a different node

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get a list to query as desired. Full disclosure, it may not be possible and if that's the case then at least it will provide me with some closure. I want to query a friend's list based on presence, where friends who are active are queried on top.

Here is my database structure:

```
friendships 
   $UID
      $UID: true

users
  $UID
    active:true/false
```

I need the list to stay synced so I need to use `.on('value')`. I've tried a couple different methods using `child_added` as well as iterating through a `snapshot` using `snapshot.forEach()` and pushing the `childSnapshot key:value` pairs into an array so I could then use `lodash` to order the list via the `active` key on the client side, but ran into the issue of it pushing a "new" item into the array for each `active` value change so there would be multiple items for any given user.

Any help or insight would be appreciated, spent the majority of yesterday attempting to figure this out before resorting back to an unorganized list using the following code:

```
const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
firebase.database().ref(`/friendships/${currentUser.uid}`).on('value, snapshot => { //redux dispatch action, payload: snapshot.val() })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no great solution for this. Firebase doesn't have any sort of join or join query, so you could do `usersRef.orderByChild('active').equalTo(true)`, but that will just return you all active users. You'll need to do separate queries to pull in their friendships.